# How I can generate PDF document with Nreco PDF Generator?

Tags: c#, jquery, database

I'm using NReco pdf generator library in my MVC solution to generate the PDF document from HTML. The code is working perfectly fine on my local machine and test instance as well. But when I deployed the code on the production instance (with OS Win2012), the code is throwing below error code.

> Cannot generate PDF: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentAccessDenied (exit code: 1)

I've already tried checking the external references like js, imgaes and CSS in my HTML docs, but there is nothing

```js
HtmlToPdfConverter htmlPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
var testFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ExportSuppliers/"), "Evaluation_" + date + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf");
htmlPdfConverter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "  --load-media-error-handling ignore";
htmlPdfConverter.Size = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageSize.Letter;
htmlPdfConverter.Margins = new PageMargins {
  Left = 10, Right = 10, Top = 25, Bottom = 25
};
htmlPdfConverter.GeneratePdf(content, null, testFile);
return testFile;
```

Comment: I'm getting the same issue and can't find the solution.